# How to put background after anchor tag throw css?

Tags: css

May be possible in css with out change HTML if yes please tell me .

I want to say how to put background images after anchor tag with css

**As like this**

[image]

**My code is**

```
<div class="right-f">
                <span>Connect with us:</span>
                <a href="#" rel="twit"></a>
                <a href="#" rel="fb"></a>
                <a href="#" rel="in"></a>
                <a href="#" rel="mail"></a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

```
.right-f a[rel="twit"] {
    background-image: ...
}
.right-f a[rel="fb"] {
    background-image: ...
}
.right-f a[rel="etc"] {
```